# Laravel getting HttpException error when i post form by using ajax

Tags: php, laravel

in Laravel i want to post simple form data form by using `Ajax` i get this error:

```
exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException"
```

for example:

**View:**

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="checkPageForAddToSystem">
    {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="page_name">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">
            close
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            add
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery Ajax:**

```
$('#checkPageForAddToSystem').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/panel/addInstagramPageByAjax',
        header: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**Route:**

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Dashboard', 'middleware' => ['auth:web'], 'prefix' => 'panel'], function () {
    $this->post('addInstagramPageByAjax', 'ManageInstagramController@addInstagramPageByAjax');
});
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public function addInstagramPageByAjax(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(['sate' => true]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example usage for setting ajax header with CSRF-TOKEN ,

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
       }
  })
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: yes i'm sure thats name is `_token`, but your helpful code resolve my problem, `header` couldn't work inside `$.ajax`

Comment: well, Why don't vote this as right answer for the other people.

Comment: I had forgotten :)  i accept and upvoted your answer, ok? :)